# updating controller over service not updating view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

in my app I have an "Maps" to show and handle things on maps. A `CtrlMap` controller display the map and shows an marker. The `watchPosMap` watches position changes. 3rd there is an service called `markerService` which hold the properties (location) of the marker.

The structure looks like that.

`[CtrlMap] <-> [MarkerService] <- [watchPosMap]`

This is the service:

```
MyMapApp.service('MarkerService', function () {
    //set initial marker if no one exists
    if (property == undefined)
    {
        var property = {
            latitude: 44.49,
            longitude: -108.42};
    }
    return {
        getP: function () {
            return property;
        },
        setP: function(lat,lng) {
            consolie.info('Have new marker properties:', lat,lng);
            property = {
                latitude: lat,
                longitude: lng};
        }
    };
});
```

On startup, the `CtrlMap` controller gets the default marker settings in that way: `$scope.marker = MarkerService.getP()`. That works well.

If the position of the device is changed, the  `watchPosMap` includes an `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` method with an callback, that calls the service `MarkerService` in order to set the new marker parameter.

This is my `watchPosMap` controller:

```
MyMapApp.controller('watchPosMap', ['$scope', 'MarkerService', function($scope) {            
$scope.watchMyPositionChangesID = 
          navigator.geolocation
                    .watchPosition(function(data) {
                        mapScope=angular.element(document.getElementById('id_map'))
                                .scope();
                        angular.element(document.getElementById('id_map'))
                                .injector().get("MarkerService")
                                .setP(data.coords.latitude,data.coords.longitude);
                        mapScope.$apply();
                       },
                       function(e){$scope.errorMsg=e;},
                       { timeout: 30000 }
                      );

}]);
```

Setting the marker property works, but the view is not updated. Is there anything todo to trigger the view update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in appropriate scope, then you have to update scope as you are modifying things outside angular.

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('id_map')).scope().$apply();
```

EDIT after comment:

Your scope marker is not updated event though it is set in service. It has to updated before you use $apply()

```
mapScope.marker = angular.element(document.getElementById('id_map'))
                            .injector().get("MarkerService")
                            .getP();
```

EDIT 2: More Cleaner way
$apply of scope has a callback function which you can use to achieve the same

```
navigator.geolocation
                .watchPosition(function(data) {
                     mapscope = angular.element(document.getElementById('id_map')).scope()
                     mapscope.$apply(function(scope){
                       MarkerService.setP(data.coords.latitude,data.coords.longitude); 
                       scope.marker = MarkerService.getP();
                     });
                   },
                   function(e){$scope.errorMsg=e;},
                   { timeout: 30000 }
                  );
```

Comment: I still use $apply(). I edit my question: please take a look at  the `watchPosMap`controller.

Comment: The service properties have updated but I'm afraid the marker is not updated. You need to update mapScope.marker = angular.element(document.getElementById('id_map'))
                                .injector().get("MarkerService")
                                .getP(); before you use $apply()

Comment: yeah! That's it! :-)  I'm wondering, if my solution is the right way to combine angularjs and legacy JS?!

Comment: `I hope,angular.element(document.getElementById('id_map')).scope() is the same scope of watchPosMap controller` it's an different controller, but same app/module. I'm not sure: is this the same scope? I don't think so, right?

Comment: Updated my answer, grab the scope of map controller and use the callback function of that scope for more cleaner way.